# c, linux - using pthread.h in kernel

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm trying to test the validity of a 9*9 sudoku problem and the results should be printed via `printk(KERN_INFO "blablabla")`. I've tried two methods to compile my c file, `make` and `gcc myfile.c myfile -o -lpthread`. However, none of them worked.

When I called `make` it threw me with an fatal error: pthread.h: no such file or directory but it is right in the path `/usr/include`.

Then I found some recommendations from the net so I tried `gcc` this time. Unfortunately, I got a bunch of errors after calling `gcc myfile.c myfile -o -lpthread` such as

`/usr/include/linux/list.h: In function 'INIT_LIST_HEAD': /usr/include/linux/list.h:27:17: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct list_head'`

and

`error: unknown type name 'bool'`,

to name but a few. The point is that I got these errors **after** I upgrade my softwares via `sudo apt-get update -y`.

Here's the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

typedef struct
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int (* board)[9];
} parameters;

void * find_rows(void * params);

void * find_cols(void * params);

void * check_valid(void * params);

/***************
 * ENTRY POINT
 **************/
int thread_init(void)
{
    // ====== Create the board =======
    int board[9][9] = {
            {6, 2, 4, 5, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7},
            {5, 1, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 4},
            {8, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 9, 5},
            {1, 4, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 2, 9},
            {9, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1},
            {7, 6, 2, 3, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8},
            {3, 7, 1, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 2},
            {4, 9, 6, 1, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3},
            {2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 1, 6}
        };

    /*int  i, j = 0;
    size_t count;
    int board[9][9];
    char *line = (char *) malloc(100);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while(getline(&line, &count, file) != -1) {
        for (count > 0; count--; j++)
            sscanf(line, "%d", &board[i][j]);
        i++;
    }*/

    parameters * data = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data->row = 0;
    data->col = 0;
    data->board = board;

    // ====== Create the parameters for the 3x3 threads ======

    // First 3x3
    parameters * data1 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data1->row = 0;
    data1->col = 0;
    data1->board = board;

    // Second 3x3
    parameters * data2 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data2->row = 0;
    data2->col = 3;
    data2->board = board;

    // Third 3x3
    parameters * data3 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data3->row = 0;
    data3->col = 6;
    data3->board = board;

    // Fourth 3x3
    parameters * data4 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data4->row = 3;
    data4->col = 0;
    data4->board = board;

    // Fifth 3x3
    parameters * data5 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data5->row = 3;
    data5->col = 3;
    data5->board = board;

    // Sixth 3x3
    parameters * data6 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data6->row = 3;
    data6->col = 6;
    data6->board = board;

    // Seventh 3x3
    parameters * data7 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data7->row = 6;
    data7->col = 0;
    data7->board = board;

    // Eighth 3x3
    parameters * data8 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data8->row = 6;
    data8->col = 3;
    data8->board = board;

    // Ninth 3x3
    parameters * data9 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data9->row = 6;
    data9->col = 6;
    data9->board = board;

    // ====== Create the threads ======
    pthread_t thread_rows, thread_cols, thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4, thread5, thread6, thread7, thread8, thread9;

    // ====== Create the return values for the threads ======
    void * all_rows;
    void * all_cols;
    void * square1;
    void * square2;
    void * square3;
    void * square4;
    void * square5;
    void * square6;
    void * square7;
    void * square8;
    void * square9;

    // ====== Initialize the threads ======
    pthread_create(&thread_rows, NULL, find_rows, (void *) data);
    pthread_create(&thread_cols, NULL, find_cols, (void *) data);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data2);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data3);
    pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data4);
    pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data5);
    pthread_create(&thread6, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data6);
    pthread_create(&thread7, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data7);
    pthread_create(&thread8, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data8);
    pthread_create(&thread9, NULL, check_valid, (void *) data9);

    // ======= Wait for all threads to finish their tasks =======
    pthread_join(thread_rows, &all_rows);
    pthread_join(thread_cols, &all_cols);
    pthread_join(thread1, &square1);
    pthread_join(thread2, &square2);
    pthread_join(thread3, &square3);
    pthread_join(thread4, &square4);
    pthread_join(thread5, &square5);
    pthread_join(thread6, &square6);
    pthread_join(thread7, &square7);
    pthread_join(thread8, &square8);
    pthread_join(thread9, &square9);

    // ====== Check whether the Sudoku Puzzle was solved ======
    if (    (int)(uintptr_t) all_rows == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) all_cols == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square1 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square2 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square3 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square4 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square5 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square6 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square7 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square8 == 1 &&
            (int)(uintptr_t) square9 == 1 )
    {
        printf("The Sudoku Puzzle is solved!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The Sudoku Puzzle is NOT solved.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void * find_rows(void * params) {
    parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
    int startRow = data->row;
    int startCol = data->col;
    for (int i = startRow; i < 9; ++i) {
        int row[10] = {0};
        for (int j = startCol; j < 9; ++j) {
            int val = data->board[i][j];
            if (row[val] != 0) {
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                row[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}

void * find_cols(void * params) {
    parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
    int startRow = data->row;
    int startCol = data->col;
    for (int i = startCol; i < 9; ++i) {
        int col[10] = {0};
        for (int j = startRow; j < 9; ++j) {
            int val = data->board[j][i];
            if (col[val] != 0) {
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                col[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}

void * check_valid(void * params) {
    parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
    int startRow = data->row;
    int startCol = data->col;
    int saved[10] = {0};
    for (int i = startRow; i < startRow + 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = startCol; j < startCol + 3; ++j) {
            int val = data->board[i][j];
            if (saved[val] != 0) {
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                saved[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}

void thread_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
}

module_init( thread_init );
module_exit( thread_exit );
```

I just can't figure out what went wrong...and no idea how to debug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: POSIX threads are for  *user-space* processes not kernel modules

Comment: What is your goal? Learn programming? Learn C? Learn POSIX threads? Learn kernel programming? Please **edit your question** to motivate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Don't use `<pthread.h>` in kernel code

You are very ***confused*** about the difference between [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) code and application ([user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space)) code. You should **avoid writing kernel code.** Read about [CPU modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes).

<sup>(you need to become a guru about C and about Linux application programming before daring writing a single line of kernel code, even a trivial [kernel module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module))</sup>

Kernel code is for stuff like [device drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver), not for Sudoku-s. Of course, you cannot use pthread in kernel code : the kernel is *implementing* threads by *providing* the [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall to applications. The POSIX C library -your `libc.so`, generally the GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)- is implementing [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) with the help of many [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) -listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)-, including `clone` and [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html).

**Read [*Operating Systems: Three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)** to understand more the role of OSes.

> I just can't figure out what went wrong

**Your entire approach is wrong**. *Throw your code away.*

---

### Learn multi-threaded POSIX application programming

Read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (and [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) then [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html)...) to learn how to **write Linux application code**.

Take several days to **read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).**

Then, code some application program using Posix threads (so having a `main` and calling [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) and [pthread_join(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)) to solve your sudoku. You'll probably need [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) and [conditional variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) for synchronization.

If you want to learn kernel programming, start with some much simpler task. Before that, become extremely fluent with Linux application programming.

<sup>(adding [kernel threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#KERNEL) is really difficult; they are not POSIX threads at all. Leave that to advanced kernel developers; learn first about user-space thread programming, it is difficult enough.)</sup>

So give up your kernel programming idea. Focus on learning C programming and POSIX application programming (that takes [many](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) years).

Compile your ([user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space)) code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve it to get no warnings. Learn to use the [`gcc` compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools like [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) or [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html), the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [address sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and other [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html).